# шифрование файла в Delphi

Tags: delphi, шифрование, aes

Использую [оболочку OpenSll](https://github.com/lminuti/Delphi-OpenSSL)

```
uses
  windows,
  classes,
  IOUtils,
  System.SysUtils,
  OpenSSL.Core,
  OpenSSL.EncUtils,
  OpenSSL.libeay32,
  OpenSSL.RSAUtils,
  OpenSSL.SMIMEUtils;

var
  SourceStream,DestStream:tfilestream;
  EncUtil :TEncUtil;
  Source,Dest:string;

begin

  Source:='C:\Users\admin\Desktop\info.txt';
  Dest:=  'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\info_enc.txt';

  SourceStream := TFileStream.Create(Source, fmOpenRead);
  DestStream := TFileStream.Create(Dest, fmCreate);



  EncUtil := TEncUtil.Create;
  try
    EncUtil.UseBase64 := True;
    EncUtil.Passphrase := 'пароль';
    EncUtil.Cipher := 'AES-256';
    EncUtil.Encrypt(SourceStream, DestStream );
  finally
    EncUtil.Free;
  end;

  SourceStream.Free;
  DestStream.Free;

end.
```

шифрование работает. т.е берется оригинальный файл и шифруется его копия.

но как сделать, чтобы шифровался именно оригинальный файл, а не его копия ?
в потоках не силен, не могу реализовать.

Comment: После шифрования скопировать результат в оригинальный файл `TFile.Copy(Dest, Source, True);`

Comment: Или вторым потоком использовать `TMemoryStream`, и сохранить через третий опять TFileStream.

Comment: @Alex R. спасибо. второй способ подошел.

Comment: EncUtil.Encrypt(SourceStream, SourceStream);попробуйте в некоторых алгоритмах это допустимо так будет намного быстрее если файл будет огромным 2й способ не пойдет